# What is a faster method to implement Sign in with Oauth2?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

How to implement a faster oauth2? I tried implementing Oauth that was described here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/. However after implementing it, the page now loads about **27,450%** slower!

What I would like to happen is that there is only a button image for Google Sign in then:

```
1. When a user click that button, it sends him to accounts.google.com/o/auth
2. When the user successfully log in, accounts.google.com sends to the website server the basic information
3. Then the server just parse that information using php. (Maybe using GET request, if not maybe a GET request to a token identifying the user at that moment)
```

Here is the code I that slowed down the page load by more than **27,000%**!

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Page load is determined using Chrome DevTool.

Comment: How did you measure the slowness ? Did you measure request response times or used a stopwatch when user login ?

Comment: page load, chrome devtool